# Positive to negative rail if Opamp has Single Supply

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

Can the output go to -5V to 5V if an opamp has a rail supply voltage VDD = 5V and VSS = 0V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a normal op-amp cannot output voltages that are not between the supply rails. Some can get very close (millivolts) and others can only get within volts of the rails.